# Show that $(V_{n})_{n \le N}$ is a $\mathcal{F}_n$-martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

First are related definitions from my lecture note:

> A $\textbf{filtration}$ on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a sequence $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ of sub-sigma fields of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{F}_{n} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$ for all $n$.
>
> A $\textbf{stochastic process}$ is a collection of random variables defined on the same probability space.
>
> A stochastic process $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ is $\textbf{adapted}$ to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ if $X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-measurable for all $n$.
>
> A process $(X_{n}, \mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ is a $\textbf{martingale}$ if
>
> - $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ is a filtration and $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ is adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$.
> - $X_{n}$ is integrable for all $n$.
> - $\mathbb{E} [X_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_{n}]=X_{n}$ for all $n$.

Then I have the following exercise:

> [image]
> It's implicitly understood that all random variables are real-valued.

I try to prove that $V_n$ is integrable by looking at the summand $H_{k} (X_{k}-X_{k-1})$. Because $H_{k} (X_{k}-X_{k-1})$ is measurable, it suffices to show that $H_{k} (X_{k}-X_{k-1})$ is bounded. Unfortunately, I can not see how to prove this claim from the facts that $(X_{n})_{n}$ is a $\mathcal{F}_n$-martingale and $(H_{n})_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-predictable.

Could you please leave me some hints to finish it? Many thanks!

Comment: Well, as it stands, it's wrong. You need some assumption on $H_k$ guaranteeing integrability (the most common would be boundedness). For instance, if $H_k\equiv H$ for every $k$ and some non-$L^1$ variable $H$ which is $\mathcal{F}_1$-measurable, then the above is probably not integrable.

Comment: Thank you so much @WoolierThanThou ;)